# Determine live/development status of Facebook application

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I thought this was going to be easy, but I can't find any open graph fields that correspond to whether or not a Facebook application is in live or development mode.

I had my 'live mode' revoked due to a missing privacy policy and didn't find out for a month. I'd like to set up a daily check to make sure the app is running

In other words how do I programatically get the state of this switch? I'm expecting it to be a read only field.

[image]

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/application

Comment: Don’t see any way to do that. _“and didn't find out for a month”_ - pretty sure Facebook would send out a developer alert in such a situation.

Comment: I'm only using it for Facebook login / analytics and the emails were going to an account I don't always monitor. The alerts in the website suddenly appeared yesterday. I often get outdated alerts such as how much I spent on ads a month ago. Fewer people than i expected ever use the login so it took a while for someone to complain.